# ASP.NET Identity 2 Remember me not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

So I am using the default implementation of individual authentication provided with a ASP.NET MVC project everything works fine except the remember me function, I've noticed that after a period of time the remember me no longer works.
I've been over all the questions about this on stack overflow and tried solutions for it but nothing's worked so far. I've also noticed that this issue has been fixed by the people who make Identity in version 2, well I'm on version 2.2.1 from the default install.
Is there something that I'm meant to change to make this work? I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: You should link or quote other solutions you have tried without success, for us not to suggest their same fix in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Startup.Auth.cs file change the default validateInterval value from 30 mins to 0

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {                  

                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator
            .OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser, int>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0),
                regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) =>
                    user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager),
                getUserIdCallback: (id) => (id.GetUserId<int>()))
            }
        });
```

Comment: Maybe adding more explanation would help. Bottom line: ticket timeout is short by default, and 'remember me' does not change the timeout, it only causes the browser not to flush the ticket when closed/reopened. Need to put a longer or 'never expire' timeout. Drawback: timeouts does apply to both use cases, 'remember' and 'not remember'. An unwary user forgetting to close the browser/session though not having tick 'remember' will not be 'saved' by a short timeout. Quite a flaw for an auth system imo.

Comment: @Frédéric That explanation makes sense thanks, my project does not need to be very secure(no sensitive information besides email), therefore I think this solution will work reasonable well. Having remember me work is more important than not having the user logged out when they're idle for a timespan